# Multiple rows multiple columns to single row multiple column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have data like

```
name    | type1 | type2
======================    
abc     |  YES  | 
abc     |       |  Yes
```

I want this data to be like

```
name| type1 | type2
==================
abc  | YES  |YES
```

Please help me with the query.

Comment: How did the data end up being in the CURRENT format to begin with? Instead of further processing what you have so far, you should GO BACK to the problem statement, since you should address that in your CURRENT QUERY, not as an ADDITION to what you already have.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of *aggregating*:

```
SQL> with test (name, type1, type2) as
  2    (select 'abc', 'YES', null  from dual union all
  3     select 'abc', null , 'Yes' from dual
  4    )
  5  select name, max(type1) type1, max(type2) type2
  6  from test
  7  group by name;

NAM TYP TYP
--- --- ---
abc YES Yes

SQL>
```